# Cannot match parentheses in regex group

Tags: c#, .net, regex

This is a regular expression, evaluated in .NET

I have the following input:

```
${guid->newguid()}
```

And I want to produce two matching groups, a character sequence after the `${` and before `}`, which are split by `->`  :

- guid
- newguid()

The pattern I am using is the following:

```
([^(?<=\${)(.*?)(?=})->]+)
```

But this doesn't match the parentheses, I am getting only the following matches:

- guid
- newguid

How can I modify the regex so I get the desired groups?

Comment: Try [`\${([^}]*?)->([^}]*)}`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%24%7b%28%5b%5e%7d%5d*%3f%29-%3e%28%5b%5e%7d%5d*%29%7d&i=%24%7bguid-%3enewguid%28%29%7d).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks this seems to be working. I am getting a match and this has 3 groups, the first: ${guid->newguid()}, the second: guid and the third: newguid()
Care to explain please why the regex I previously tried didn't work? Wasn't supposed the (.*) to match all the occurrences?

Comment: In short: you ruined the regex by placing the sequence of patterns into a negated character class.

Comment: Another one matching the two groups: `\${(.*)->(.*)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex - `([^(?<=\${)(.*?)(?=})->]+)` - match 1+ characters other than those defined in the negated character class (that is, 1 or more chars other than `(`, `?`, `<`, etc).

I suggest using a matching regex like this:

```
\${([^}]*?)->([^}]*)}
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%24%7B%28%5B%5E%7D%5D*%3F%29-%3E%28%5B%5E%7D%5D*%29%7D&i=%24%7Bguid-%3Enewguid%28%29%7D)

The results you need are in `match.Groups[1]` and `match.Groups[2]`.

**Pattern details**:

- `\${` - match `${` literal character sequence
- `([^}]*?)` - Group 1 capturing 0+ chars other than `}` as few as possible
- `->` - a literal char sequence `->`
- `([^}]*)` - Group 2 capturing 0+ chars other than `}` as many as possible
- `}` - a literal `}`.

If you know that you only have *word* chars inside, you may simplify the regex to a mere

```
\${(\w+)->(\w+\(\))}
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%24%7B%28%5Cw%2B%29-%3E%28%5Cw%2B%5C%28%5C%29%29%7D&i=%24%7Bguid-%3Enewguid%28%29%7D). However, it is much less generic.

Answer (score 1):

Your input structure is always `${identifier->identifier()}`? If this is the case, you can user `^\$\{([^-]+)->([^}]+)\}$`.

Otherwise, you can modify your *regexpr* to `([^?<=\${.*??=}\->]+)`: using this *rexexpr* you should match input and get the desired groups: `uid` and `newguid()`. The *key change* is the quoting of `-` char, which is intendend as *range* operator without quoting and forces you to insert parenthesis in your pattern - but... `[^......(....)....]` excludes parenthesis from the match.

I hope than can help!

EDIT: testing with https://regex101.com helped me a lot... showing me that `-` was intended as *range* operator.

Comment: This one would *not* match `${my-identifier->identifier()}`